# Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 dual boot . How to expand the size of Windows partition?

Tags: dual-boot

I don't want to lose any data or else i would installed them again.
There must be a way to increase the partition size.

Comment: Are you asking how to resize the Windows partition?

Comment: Could you be more specific about providing info about the partitions and free space .Please  take a look [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/25707/how-can-i-increase-the-size-of-a-windows-2003-ntfs-partition) , is this similar to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Gparted, a great disk partitioning software.
It is recommended by many people.

Download it from [here](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php)
Download the .iso file and boot from the live cd
You can move, re-size, copy. delete, create, etc partitions at will.

Another alternative you have is to boot from an Ubuntu live cd/usb and use Gparted from it.

*Note* - Although the download link says

> **Editing partitions has the potential to cause LOSS of DATA.**

That is not much encountered. As long as you are resizing onto an empty unallocated space you are safe.
I myself have done resizing many times and have never ever come across any data loss.
 Well, if you are a pessimist or tend to get a bit panicky at times, i would suggest a back-up of the **most** important data.

Comment: I did what you asked, booted from the live cd of gparted. I lowered the size of ubuntu so available 25 gb space created. But i can't resize the size of windows. It keeps saying the maximum is 50 gb when i have 25 availbable gb space.. if u want a screnshot i can show u...

Comment: @Bong.Da.City see if these helps http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-gparted-to-resize-your-windows-vista-partition/